# Android - Subir imagen a servidor

Tags: android, imagen, studio

Tengo problemas para subir imagenes desde el dispositivo hacia un servidor web.

Si utilizo la cámara del dispositivo y luego en mi app, la selecciono de la galería **no la sube**.
Si abro la cámara desde mi app, tomo la fotografía, **a veces la sube y a veces no**.
Si abro la galería desde mi app, selecciono una foto/imagen, **si sube la imagen**

Si se les ocurre alguna idea para implementar, es bienvenida.

En el servidor hay un PHP simple.
Abajo dejo el código del fragment que hace el trabajo desde el lado del dispositivo y el código PHP.

PHP

```
<?php

$file_path = "uploads/";

$file_path = $file_path . basename( $_FILES['uploaded_file']['name']);
$title =$_FILES['title'];

if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploaded_file']['tmp_name'], $file_path)) {
    chmod($file_path, 0755);
    echo "success";
} else{
    echo "fail";
}
?>
```

Android (java)

```
    package com.mikolbe.donasmanager.ui.home;
    
    import android.Manifest;
    import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
    import android.app.DatePickerDialog;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
    import android.database.Cursor;
    import android.net.Uri;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.os.Environment;
    import android.provider.MediaStore;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.Gravity;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.CompoundButton;
    import android.widget.DatePicker;
    import android.widget.EditText;
    import android.widget.ImageView;
    import android.widget.LinearLayout;
    import android.widget.Switch;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    import android.widget.Toast;
    
    import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;
    import androidx.core.content.FileProvider;
    import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
    import androidx.navigation.Navigation;
    
    import com.mikolbe.donasmanager.R;
    import com.mikolbe.donasmanager.constants.APIConstants;
    import com.mikolbe.donasmanager.server.Caller;
    import com.mikolbe.donasmanager.server.UploadFile;
    import com.mikolbe.donasmanager.ui.custom.DatePickerFragment;
    
    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.text.MessageFormat;
    import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
    import java.util.Date;
    
    import static android.app.Activity.RESULT_CANCELED;
    import static android.app.Activity.RESULT_OK;
    
    public class FragmentNovedad extends Fragment {
    
        final int REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO = 1;
        final int REQUEST_PCIK_PHOTO = 2;
        String currentPhotoPath = "", currentPhotoPathAux;
    
        Uri photoURI;
        ImageView img_preview;
        View custom_toast;
        String titulo, descripcion, producto_nombre;
        int producto_precio;
        long fecha_inicio, fecha_fin;
        boolean isProducto;
    
    
        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_novedad, container, false);
            custom_toast = inflater.inflate(R.layout.toast, container.findViewById(R.id.toast_layout_root));
            EditText txt_producto_nombre = v.findViewById(R.id.txt_producto_nombre);
            EditText txt_producto_precio = v.findViewById(R.id.txt_producto_precio);
    
            LinearLayout linear_soy_producto = v.findViewById(R.id.linear_soy_producto);
    
            EditText txt_novedad_fecha_inicio = v.findViewById(R.id.txt_novedad_fecha_inicio);
            txt_novedad_fecha_inicio.setOnClickListener(v1 -> {showDatePickerDialog(txt_novedad_fecha_inicio);});
    
            EditText txt_novedad_fecha_fin = v.findViewById(R.id.txt_novedad_fecha_fin);
            txt_novedad_fecha_fin.setOnClickListener(v1 -> {showDatePickerDialog(txt_novedad_fecha_fin);});
    
            @SuppressLint("UseSwitchCompatOrMaterialCode")
            Switch swt_destacada = v.findViewById(R.id.swt_destacada);
    
            @SuppressLint("UseSwitchCompatOrMaterialCode")
            Switch swt_producto = v.findViewById(R.id.swt_producto);
            swt_producto.setChecked(false);
            isProducto = false;
            swt_producto.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams parm;
                    int width = 0, height = 0;
                    isProducto = isChecked;
    
                    if (isChecked) {
                        linear_soy_producto.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        width = LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
                        height = LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
                    } else if (!isChecked) {
                        width = 0;
                        height = 0;
                        linear_soy_producto.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    }
    
                    parm = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(width, height);
                    parm.setMargins(0, 5, 0, 0);
                    linear_soy_producto.setPadding(5,5,5,5);
                    linear_soy_producto.setLayoutParams(parm);
                }
            });
    
            EditText txt_novedad_titulo = v.findViewById(R.id.txt_novedad_titulo);
            EditText txt_novedad_descripcion = v.findViewById(R.id.txt_novedad_descripcion);
    
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
                    ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
    
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(), new String[] {Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 8);
            }
    
            img_preview = v.findViewById(R.id.img_preview);
            ImageView img_camera = v.findViewById(R.id.img_camera);
            img_camera.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
    
                    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
    
                        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(), new String[] {Manifest.permission.CAMERA}, 8);
                    } else {
    
                        Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                        if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getActivity().getPackageManager()) != null) {
                            File photoFile = null;
                            try {
                                photoFile = createImageFile();
                            } catch (IOException ex) {
                                // --
                            }
                            if (photoFile != null) {
                                photoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(getActivity(),
                                        "com.mikolbe.donasmanager.fileprovider",
                                        photoFile);
                                takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoURI);
                                startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
    
            ImageView img_gallery = v.findViewById(R.id.img_gallery);
            img_gallery.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                    startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent , REQUEST_PCIK_PHOTO );//one can be replaced with any action code
                }
            });
    
            Button btn_upload = v.findViewById(R.id.btn_upload);
            btn_upload.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    titulo = txt_novedad_titulo.getText().toString();
                    descripcion = txt_novedad_descripcion.getText().toString();
                    producto_nombre = txt_producto_nombre.getText().toString();
                    if (!txt_producto_precio.getText().toString().equals(""))
                        producto_precio = Integer.parseInt(txt_producto_precio.getText().toString());
                    else
                        producto_precio = 0;
                    fecha_inicio = DateConvert(txt_novedad_fecha_inicio.getText().toString());
                    fecha_fin = DateConvert(txt_novedad_fecha_fin.getText().toString());
    
                    if (Validate()) {
                        getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                fecha_inicio = fecha_inicio * 1000000;
                                fecha_fin = (fecha_fin * 1000000) + 235959;
    
                                UploadFile uploadFile = new UploadFile();
                                try {
                                    Log.e("currentPhotoPath", currentPhotoPath);
                                    String result = uploadFile.execute(currentPhotoPath).get();
                                    String[] array = currentPhotoPath.split("/");
                                    String archivo_nombre = "";
                                    archivo_nombre = array[array.length-1];
                                    int destacado = 0;
    
                                    if (swt_destacada.isChecked())
                                        destacado = 1;
    
                                    Caller caller;
                                    String url;
                                    if (isProducto){
                                        caller = new Caller();
                                        url = MessageFormat.format(APIConstants.URLNuevoProducto, producto_nombre, String.valueOf(producto_precio), archivo_nombre);
                                        result = caller.execute(url).get();
                                    }
    
                                    caller = new Caller();
                                    // -- Alta Novedad
                                    url = MessageFormat.format(APIConstants.URLNuevaNovedad, titulo,
                                            archivo_nombre, StringParse(descripcion), String.valueOf(fecha_inicio), String.valueOf(fecha_fin), destacado);
                                    result = caller.execute(url).get();
    
                                    ShowToast("Se agregó una nueva novedad", R.drawable.ic_menu_donut);
                                    Navigation.findNavController(getActivity(), R.id.nav_host_fragment).navigateUp();
    
                                } catch (Exception ex) {
                                    Log.e("Result", String.valueOf(ex.getStackTrace()));
                                }
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }
            });
    
            return v;
        }
    
        @Override
        public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
            Log.e("onActivityResult", "-----");
            Log.e("resultCode", "resultCode");
            Log.e("requestCode", "requestCode");
            Log.e("currentPhotoPath-in", currentPhotoPath);
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                switch (requestCode) {
                    case REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO:
                        img_preview.setImageURI(photoURI);
                        currentPhotoPath = currentPhotoPathAux;
                        break;
                    case REQUEST_PCIK_PHOTO:
                        Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
                        img_preview.setImageURI(selectedImage);
                        currentPhotoPath = getRealPathFromURI(selectedImage);
                        break;
                }
            } else if(resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED){
                // -- volver al path de imagen anterior
    
            }
            Log.e("currentPhotoPath-out", currentPhotoPath);
        }
    
        private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
            String imageFileName = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss_").format(new Date());
            File storageDir = getActivity().getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
            File image = File.createTempFile(
                    imageFileName,  /* prefix */
                    ".jpg",         /* suffix */
                    storageDir      /* directory */
            );
    
            currentPhotoPathAux = image.getAbsolutePath();
            return image;
        }
    
        public String getRealPathFromURI(Uri contentUri) {
    
            // can post image
            String [] proj={MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
            Cursor cursor = getActivity().managedQuery( contentUri,
                    proj, // Which columns to return
                    null,       // WHERE clause; which rows to return (all rows)
                    null,       // WHERE clause selection arguments (none)
                    null); // Order-by clause (ascending by name)
            int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
            cursor.moveToFirst();
    
            return cursor.getString(column_index);
        }
    
        private String StringParse(String texto){
            char[] aaa = texto.toCharArray();
            String result = "";
            int ascii;
            for (char x : aaa){
                String y = String.valueOf(x);
                ascii = (int) y.toCharArray()[0];
                if (ascii == 10)
                {
                    y = "\\n";
                }
                result += y;
            }
    
            return result;
        }
    
        private boolean Validate(){
            if (titulo.trim().equals("")){
                ShowToast("Debe ingresar el título", R.drawable.ic_wrong_way);
                return false;
            }
    
            if (descripcion.trim().equals("")){
                ShowToast("Debe ingresar una descripción", R.drawable.ic_wrong_way);
                return false;
            }
    
            if (currentPhotoPath.equals("")){
                ShowToast("Debe seleccionar una imagen", R.drawable.ic_wrong_way);
                return false;
            }
    
            if (fecha_inicio == 0){
                ShowToast("Debe ingresar fecha de inicio", R.drawable.ic_wrong_way);
                return false;
            }
    
            if (fecha_fin == 0){
                ShowToast("Debe ingresar fecha de fin", R.drawable.ic_wrong_way);
                return false;
            }
    
            if (fecha_inicio > fecha_fin){
                ShowToast("Fecha inicio debe ser anterior a fecha fin", R.drawable.ic_wrong_way);
                return false;
            }
    
            if (isProducto){
                if (producto_nombre.trim().equals("")){
                    ShowToast("Ingrese nombre del producto", R.drawable.ic_wrong_way);
                    return false;
                }
    
                if (producto_precio == 0){
                    ShowToast("Ingrese precio del producto", R.drawable.ic_wrong_way );
                    return false;
                }
            }
    
            return true;
        }
    
        private void ShowToast(String text, int image)
        {
            // -- R.drawable.ic_wrong_way
            TextView txt_toast_message = custom_toast.findViewById(R.id.txt_toast_message);
            ImageView image_toast = custom_toast.findViewById(R.id.image_toast);
            image_toast.setImageResource(image);
    
            txt_toast_message.setText(text);
            Toast toast = new Toast(getActivity());
            toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL, 0, 0);
            toast.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            toast.setView(custom_toast);
            toast.show();
        }
    
        private void showDatePickerDialog(EditText editText) {
            DatePickerFragment newFragment = DatePickerFragment.newInstance(editText.getText().toString(), new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDateSet(DatePicker datePicker, int year, int month, int day) {
                    // +1 because January is zero
                    final String selectedDate = DosDigitos(day) + "/" + DosDigitos((month+1)) + "/" + year;
                    editText.setText(selectedDate);
                }
            });
    
            newFragment.show(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager(), "datePicker");
        }
    
        private String DosDigitos(int number){
            String result = String.valueOf(number);
    
            if (number
```

```
    package com.mikolbe.donasmanager.server;
    
    import android.os.AsyncTask;
    
    import com.mikolbe.donasmanager.constants.APIConstants;
    
    import java.io.DataOutputStream;
    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.FileInputStream;
    import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
    
    import java.net.URL;
    
    public class UploadFile extends AsyncTask {
    
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
            String currentPhotoPath = strings[0];
            HttpURLConnection conn = null;
            DataOutputStream dos = null;
            String lineEnd = "\r\n";
            String twoHyphens = "--";
            String boundary = "*****";
            int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
            byte[] buffer;
            int maxBufferSize = 1024 * 1024;
            File sourceFile = new File(currentPhotoPath);
    
            String upLoadServerUri = APIConstants.URLUploadFile;
    
            try {
                // open a URL connection to the Servlet
                FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(sourceFile);
                URL url = new URL(upLoadServerUri);
    
                // Open a HTTP  connection to  the URL
                conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                conn.setDoInput(true); // Allow Inputs
                conn.setDoOutput(true); // Allow Outputs
                conn.setUseCaches(false); // Don't use a Cached Copy
                conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
                conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
                conn.setRequestProperty("ENCTYPE", "multipart/form-data");
                conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);
                conn.setRequestProperty("uploaded_file", currentPhotoPath);
    
                dos = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());
    
                dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
                dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploaded_file\";filename=\""
                        + currentPhotoPath + "\"" + lineEnd);
    
                dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
    
    
                // create a buffer of  maximum size
                bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
    
                bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
    
                // read file and write it into form...
                bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
    
                while (bytesRead > 0) {
    
                    dos.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                    bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                    bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                    bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
    
                }
    
                // send multipart form data necesssary after file data...
                dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
                dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);
    
                // Responses from the server (code and message)
                int serverResponseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
                String serverResponseMessage = conn.getResponseMessage();
    
                if (serverResponseCode == 200) {
    
                }
    
                //close the streams //
                fileInputStream.close();
                dos.flush();
                dos.close();
    
                return serverResponseMessage;
            } catch (Exception ex){
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
    
            return "FIN";
        }
    }
```

**EDIT:**
Adjunto error mostrado en consola

```
    2021-04-27 11:22:33.379 11064-11064/com.mikolbe.donasmanager E/currentPhotoPath: /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.mikolbe.donasmanager/files/Pictures/20210427_112212_9067646797071778145.jpg
    2021-04-27 11:22:33.430 11064-11985/com.mikolbe.donasmanager I/be.donasmanage: The ClassLoaderContext is a special shared library.
    2021-04-27 11:22:34.275 11064-11064/com.mikolbe.donasmanager I/Choreographer: Skipped 53 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
    2021-04-27 11:22:34.324 11064-11150/com.mikolbe.donasmanager I/OpenGLRenderer: Davey! duration=934ms; Flags=0, IntendedVsync=849781205872554, Vsync=849782085394675, OldestInputEvent=9223372036854775807, NewestInputEvent=0, HandleInputStart=849782091769682, AnimationStart=849782091829221, PerformTraversalsStart=849782093020759, DrawStart=849782132035682, SyncQueued=849782134093067, SyncStart=849782134158990, IssueDrawCommandsStart=849782134326682, SwapBuffers=849782138703990, FrameCompleted=849782140040298, DequeueBufferDuration=156000, QueueBufferDuration=258000
```

Comment: ¿Cuándo no la sube, falla silenciosamente? Si no, ¿Qué excepciones son las que tienes?

Comment: Te muestro el log:
2021-04-27 11:22:33.379 11064-11064/com.mikolbe.donasmanager E/currentPhotoPath: /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.mikolbe.donasmanager/files/Pictures/20210427_112212_9067646797071778145.jpg
2021-04-27 11:22:34.275 11064-11064/com.mikolbe.donasmanager I/Choreographer: Skipped 53 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
2021-04-27 11:22:34.324 11064-11150/com.mikolbe.donasmanager I/OpenGLRenderer: Davey! duration=934ms; Flags=0, IntendedVsync=849781205872554, Vsync=849782085394675, OldestInputEvent=9223372036854775807, NewestInputEvent=0

Comment: Imposible de leer en comentarios. Sugiero que edites tu pregunta y añadas este tipo de información, que mejorará tu chance de encontrar ayuda. Un saludo.

Comment: Faaa, si, soy malísimo para los foros.... edito el post

Comment: Busca en el logCat donde diga "Caused by" y agregalo a tu pregunta por favor.